# Title won't center

Tags: html, css

My titles won't center. As you can see the subtitle is okay, but the title is way more to the left. How can I fix this?
The website link: http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/portfolio.html

The HTML:

```
<div class="titel">Portfolio</div>
<div class="subtitel">Hier is een selectie van recentelijk werk.</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.titel {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size:   52px;
  color:       #3b3d40;
  text-align:  center;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top:  20px;
  display:     block;
}

.subtitel {
    font-family:   Adobe Caslon Pro;
    font-size:     18px;
    text-align:    center;
    margin-top:    40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Your social media icons are pushing it over.

Comment: your code runs correct without the social icons container, just tested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your website is that your social icons are floated to the right. Therefore, what you need to do is to clear the title container. For that, all you need to do is to add `clear: right;` for your `.titel`

For reference, check the [MDN documentation on the `clear` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.titel {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 52px;
  color: #3b3d40;
}

.subtitel {
  font-family: Adobe Caslon Pro;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  text-align:    center;  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="titel">Portfolio</div>
    <div class="subtitel">Hier is een selectie van recentelijk werk.</div>  
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, that should work as expected, take a look at snippet:

```css
.titel {
   font-family: Raleway;
   font-size: 52px;
   color: #3b3d40;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: 700;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: block;
}

.subtitel {
   font-family: Adobe Caslon Pro;
   font-size: 18px;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 40px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="titel">Portfolio</div>
<div class="subtitel">Hier is een selectie van recentelijk werk.</div>
```

You can also try to make `.titel` as follow:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

Another way is to add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` under div `.social`.